# Generating Interactive Tiles using Nodejs, Mapnik, and PostGIS for Leaflet

Tags: postgis, leaflet, mapnik, mapbox, node-js

I am looking to do something like [this](http://glimmer.rstudio.com/jcheng/leaflet-demo/) but where I have all the data on the same server.

I've been following through the set of tutorials @ [sparkgeo.com/labs/big/](http://sparkgeo.com/labs/big/) and I'm having some difficulty. Ultimately I'd like to get it working with `Leaflet` like the tutorial @ [sparkgeo.com/labs/bigleaflet/](http://sparkgeo.com/labs/bigleaflet/) but I can't get the version on the prior tutorial to work either. So the final version will be generating `R Shiny` interactive maps and layers from tiles accessed through `Leaflet` generated by `Postgis` by means of `node.js` using `mapnik` and `mapbox`.

The `Wax` libraries used in that tutorial have been removed so I installed [this](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-14.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/libjs-wax_5.0.1+ds2-1_all.deb.html). I pointed the tiles in the `HTML` file to `http://localhost:8000/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` and pointed to my location of `wax.g.min.js`. No census tracts are showing up with I run the `cencon.js` code. Similarly with the `Leaflet` version of the `HTML` file, I pointed to the localhost for the layers and they are not displaying. They are successfully loaded to the `PostGIS` database and changing the database login info.

OK, so I'm new to all of this and I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious. I did not alter the code other than what I previously mentioned. Is there something else I needed to do to generate the tiles @ `http://localhost:8000/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`? Also, now that `Wax` is superseded, do you have any links for more suitable tutorials using `mapbox`?

Comment: Have you tried opening Chrome's developer tools (Network tab and console, specifically) to see if there are any errors or timeouts?

Comment: Yea definitely getting `GET http://localhost:8000/10/166/395.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and so on. I am wondering if the database is too slow since it takes forever to load a table into QGIS. Will update those settings. When I just browse to one tile with the real URL it gives me nothing as well.

Comment: The Wax GitHub repo is still available, BTW: https://github.com/mapbox/wax

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. For those following along, ended up changing "localhost" to the IP of the server. Still facing issues - the tile layers are invisible. I'm putting this to bed in order to work on a quicker solution but may respond at a later time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit high time I answered, but here goes:

- Since the use of Wax is deprecated as you mentioned, [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/) are some Mapbox examples to get you started. Bear in mind that the [Leaflet API](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) is embedded into Mapbox.js and can be used hand in hand with Mapbox code.
- Using `http://localhost:8000/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` means to store the tiles in your own folder. This is good provided you don't want too many zoom levels. Otherwise, it gets really hard to manage so many tiles on your computer. You may want to clarify that for yourself first.
- If you get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on a Windows localhost to access these tiles declared by `http://localhost:8000/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, the problem may be that your js source is on a remote server, and not within the localhost folder. Naturally, the computer does not allow some untrusted js code on the internet to access the contents of your computer.

In other words, instead of adding the js library as this:

```
<script src="http://mapbox.com/foo/bar/mapbox.js"></script>
```

...download the js into your localhost folder and use this:

```
<script src="/mapbox.js"></script>
```

If this does not solve your problem, make sure your localhost server (XAMPP or whatever) has the permissions to access your filesystem.

- I believe you're using a bit too much of libraries at the same time for a simple web map. [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) is a great tool to create interactive maps with minimum effort. Combine that with Mapbox.js and your JavaScript skills so that you can create a map like in the first example you provided.

If you have the data you wish to display in CSV or some similar format, I suggest you get started with TileMill immediately.